# How to retrieve @@Identity following an ExecuteNonQuery?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm using the `ExecuteNonQuery` function and stored procedure  to insert a new record in an MSSQL database.

During testing the insert of the new record is successful. But my second call to `ExecuteScalar` and get the newly inserted record's `ID` fails. The reason for the failure according to the debugger is:

> ExecuteScalar requires an open and available Connection. The
>   connection's current state is closed.

Looking at this error it explains that the connection has been closed after the initial call to `ExecuteNonQuery`. Meaning that my code to get the `ID` won't have a valid connection to query with.

**Question:**

How can you retrieve `@@Identity` following an ExecuteNonQuery?

This is the piece of code that performs the insert in the DAL:

```
            Database db = GetConnectionString();
            string sqlCommand = "CREATE_RECORD";
            string idQuery= "Select @@Identity";
            int recID = 0;


            using (DbCommand dbCommand = db.GetStoredProcCommand(sqlCommand))
            {

                db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@Application", DbType.String, escalation.Application); 
                db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@UpdatedTime", DbType.DateTime, escalation.UpdatedTime);

                db.ExecuteNonQuery(dbCommand);
                dbCommand.CommandText = idQuery;
                recID = (int)dbCommand.ExecuteScalar();

                return recID ;
            }
```

Comment: you can use scope identity

Comment: or i willl provide one code used in stored procedure

Comment: SqlParameter PrimaryID = new SqlParameter("@PrimaryID", SqlDbType.BigInt) { Value = 0, Direction = ParameterDirection.Output };

Comment: Why not just get the identity value back directly from the stored procedure and save yourself the round trip?

Comment: I don't have access to the DB stored procedures. Would prefer to do the retrieval server side.

Comment: It should be a trivial change for the DBA to change the procedure to return the ID.  If they refuse to change it, inform them that it is a security risk and a performance concern doing it any other way and take it up with management.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**DISCLAIMER**: This is a bad idea - the correct solution is server-side (*server* in this case is SQL Server).

You may be able to do this if you use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` (which you should anyway - `@@IDENTITY` is not guaranteed to be your insert's identity) and execute your command as `CommandType.Text` instead of `CommandType.StoredProcedure`

**WARNING**: Serious security implications here, most notably *SQL Injection Attack* possibility:

```
Database db = GetConnectionString();
string sqlCommand = $"CREATE_RECORD '{escalation.Application}', '{escalation.UpdatedTime}'";
string idQuery= "Select SCOPE_IDENTITY()"
int recID = 0;

using (DbCommand dbCommand = db.GetStoredProcCommand(sqlCommand))
{
    dbCommand.CommandType = commandType.Text;

    db.ExecuteNonQuery(dbCommand);
    dbCommand.CommandText = idQuery;
    recID = (int)dbCommand.ExecuteScalar();

    return recID;
}
```

Of course, if you go this route, you might as well combine both commands into a single query:

```
Database db = GetConnectionString();
string sqlCommand = $"CREATE_RECORD '{escalation.Application}', '{escalation.UpdatedTime}'; Select SCOPE_IDENTITY()";
int recID = 0;

using (DbCommand dbCommand = db.GetStoredProcCommand(sqlCommand))
{
    dbCommand.CommandType = commandType.Text;

    //TODO: Open connection using your db object
    recID = (int)dbCommand.ExecuteScalar();
    //TODO: Close connection using your db object

    return recID;
}
```

Again, I stress that the correct solution is to fix this in SQL, not in C#. Use at your own risk!

Comment: On second thought I've asked the DBA to add an output parameter for identity like this to the CREATE_RECORD stored procedure : `OUTPUT INSERTED.ID`  Is that the correct way to output the ID after an insert?

Comment: @BrianJ, yes, that's a great way to do it - OUTPUT INSERTED.ID` will return newly inserted identity of a single row insert, before any triggers run. Here's more info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql

Answer (score 1):

You should create and open connection for each query and dispose it after query. Don't worry, there are connection pool in ADO and connection will not be physically established and closed each time. It's only a hint for ADO.NET.

```
int recID = 0;
string connStr = ProcThatGivesYouConnectionString();
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connStr))
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("CREATE_RECORD", con);
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Application", escalation.Application);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UpdatedTime", escalation.UpdatedTime);
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}

using (SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection(connStr))
{
    con2.Open();
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Select @@Identity", con2);
    recID = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();
}
```

Also you can execute both queries in one command if you want:

```
int recID = 0;
string connStr = ProcThatGivesYouConnectionString();
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connStr))
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("
EXEC CREATE_RECORD @Application = @Application, @UpdatedTime = @UpdatedTime
SELECT @@Identity", con);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Application", escalation.Application);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UpdatedTime", escalation.UpdatedTime);
    recID = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();
}
```

Comment: This won't work reliably at all. `@@IDENTITY` may not be your insert's. Suppose multiple clients execute this code simultaneously - what's in `@@IDENTITY`? It is recommended to use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`, which won't work in your set up either, as it will be out of scope in the second connection. In general, opening additional connections as you're suggesting is a terrible idea in even a moderately busy production environment.

Comment: @@IDENTITY and SCOPE_IDENTITY return the last identity value generated in any table in the current session. link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/identity-transact-sql

Comment: @CoolBots, I've modified my query. But I afraid `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` in won't work this case too. Of course It's better to modify SP to return ID, but author writes that he can't do it.

Comment: @CoolBots About SqlConnection.Open: SqlConnection **draws an open connection from the connection pool if one is available**. Otherwise, it establishes a new connection to an instance of SQL Server. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.open(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: There is a cost to *draw open connection from the connection pool..," or "establish a new conneciton..." - these are not free operations. In your code, you should also `Close` your connecitons, and wrap the `SQLCommand` you created into `using` directive, as it is an `IDisposable`.

Comment: Hope this article could help you. Connection pooling is created by microsoft to deal with this problem (We strongly recommend that you always close the connection when you are finished using it so that the connection will be returned to the pool. You can do this using either the Close or Dispose methods of the Connection object): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

object r = command.ExecuteScalar();
Convert.ToInt32(r.ToString());

To prevent the ExecuteScalar gets Specified cast is not valid error , use above